# Отобразить в QLabel определенный кусок QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Делаю анимацию, по таймеру меняется кадр, анимация состоит из 1-й картинки, в которой нарисован каждый кадр.

Как можно поместить в QLabel определенный фрагмент QPixmap?

P.s. Если QPixmap или QLabel не поддерживают такое, то что можно использовать для такого вида анимации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен метод `QPixmap::copy(int x, int y, int width, int height)`, который вернет вам `QPixmap`-копию по координатам, определенных во входных параметрах.